# Get Employees records below particular month and year(Get based on month and Year)

Tags: mysql

I have a condition, where I want to get all employees list who are registered below Jan 2022.
I want to get employees list who are Active, and who are Inactive till Jan 2022.
I want to get based on month and year only.
I have tired with my below query but not getting proper results. Any suggestions please.

```
SELECT A.id,A.first_name,A.status,B.join_date 
FROM employee AS A 
INNER JOIN employee_job_info AS B 
   ON A.id = B.employee_id 
WHERE YEAR(B.join_date)<=2022 AND MONTH(B.join_date)<=1;
```

Below is my sql fiddle link
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e329fc/1

Comment: What are the expected results from that sample data?

Comment: In my Mysql fiddle, I should get count as 9, as one employee is inactivated in febraury, so Upto jan count is 9. 
I have kept month less than condition, so its fetching details of january month only, not gettting results of other remaining months.

Leave the Inactive condition, Fo suposse, If want to get employee Upto March month.
Then its not getting results for other other, it getting date for only jan,feb & march

Comment: The fiddle is missing table and sample data for `employee_job_info` table. Also, please clarify what does `status` represent in `employee` table?

Comment: Status -1 (Active)
Status - 0(Inactive)

Please check only the sql fiddle query, not my query in the post, I have changed codition in sql fiddle for easier understanding

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, the `YEAR()/MONTH()` extraction is not necessary. As for the `status`, I don't see it being a significant condition required here. Nonetheless, I'm concerned that you may aiming for something else here instead of just a simple count. But if you really just want the count, based on your condition, then this query should be enough:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as count
FROM employee
WHERE added_on <= '2022-01-31'
  AND last_active_date <= '2022-01-31';
```